# Input field for PIN code

Tags: html, css

I want to create a form, where user can enter Email and 4 digit PIN. For PIN input I would like to use `<input type="number">` instead of regex, but I don't know how to hide entered digits.

Comment: Maybe `<input type="password">`?

Comment: See also this duplicate question (which has some great answers): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935576/how-to-make-input-type-tel-work-as-type-password

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the type `password` and HTML `maxlength` property:

```
<input type="password" name="pin" maxlength="4">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skxr9o47/

This would require some `JavaScript` validation to ensure a number was entered.

An alternative way would be to use `HTML 5` and take advantage of the `number` type (As you already have done) or the `pattern` attribute and validate it inside your form.

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="pin" pattern="[0-9]{4}" maxlength="4">
    <input type="submit" value="Validate">
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L6n9b5nr/

However, you would have to use `JavaScript` or `jQuery` to use mask the user's input.

Answer (score 7):

### Use inputmode numeric and password input

For Android and iOS you can also add `inputmode="numeric"` to an input `type="password"`. The user will get a keyboard with only numbers (the same keyboard as used for the input `type="tel"`).
Example:

```
<input name="pincode" type="password" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="4">
```

### Use a style and text input

Another option that doesn't work in every browser, is to hide the digits via the style in an input `type="text"`. Example:

```
<style>
    .pincode {
        text-security: disc;
        -webkit-text-security: disc;
        -moz-text-security: disc;
    }
</style>
<input name="pincode" type="text" class="pincode" inputmode="numeric" maxlength="4">
```

Answer (score 5):

Try the following.

Note:

- The usage of `monospace` font family as they have [uniform characters width](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13149) and in styling I'm depending on `ch` here.
- The `validateInputfunction` will esnure that only numbers are entered.
- input type of `text`  and `maxlength="4"` ensures number size doesn't exceed `4`.
- Finally, if you want to provide PIN code of more digits .e.g. 6 digits modify  `.pin-input` width = `number of pins * 1.5 ch`
- As noted by @Ferris, Firefox still doesn't support `text-security: disc;`, an alternative solution is listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67603338/20896315)

Made two pin code looks, check them out!

```js
document.querySelector('.pin-input').addEventListener('input', validateInput);

function validateInput(e) {
  const el = e.target;

  if (el.validity.patternMismatch) {
    el.value = el.value.slice(0, -1);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

```css
/* First Pin CSS */

.pin-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.pin-input {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: calc(1.6ch * 4);
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, dimgrey 0, dimgrey 1ch, transparent 0, transparent 1.6ch) 0 100%/100% 2px no-repeat;
  color: dimgrey;
  letter-spacing: .6ch;
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
  -moz-text-security: disc;
}


/* Second Pin CSS */

.box-pin-container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  height: 2ch;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.box-pin-input {
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: inherit;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  letter-spacing: 1ch;
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
  -moz-text-security: disc;
  color: gray;
  padding-left: .25ch;
  height: 1.5ch;
  margin-bottom: .05ch;
  
  background: transparent;
  width: 8ch;
}

.cell {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  outline: 2px solid lightgray;
  width: 1.5ch;
  z-index: -1;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

body {
  height: 90vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="pin-container">
  <input type="text" name="pin-code" class="pin-input" pattern="\d*" maxlength="4" title="Input 4 number PIN code" inputMode="numeric" autocomplete="off" />
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="box-pin-container">
    <input type="text" name="box-pin-code" class="box-pin-input" pattern="\d*" maxlength="4" title="Input 4 number PIN code" inputMode="numeric" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
    <div class="cell">
    </div>
    <div class="cell" style="left: 2ch;">
    </div>
    <div class="cell" style="left: 4ch;">
    </div>
    <div class="cell" style="left: 6ch;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why did you use `text-security` instead of setting input `type` to `password`? However, good approach.

Comment: @Ferris Both accomplish the same thing visually, however I used text in my application, when I don't want scripts to easily detect pin code field as password, so it appears as normal text when searching the page, it also prevent password managers from detecting them, it doesn't prevent detecting it's a password field if scripts are more tailored though. Since, it's a PIN code, it's recommended to be entered manually rather than auto completed.  You made me remember to turn off text auto complete. Thanks!

Comment: This makes perfect sense. I never thought about this aspect. To make the whole thing Firefox compatible (still no support for `text-security`) you can then include something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67603338/20896315 which makes your solution almost perfect.

Comment: @Ferris That's very helpful, I will include it in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

I feel like no one actually fully answered the question, I've combined this code from multiple posts regarding this questions and this is what I use. 4 digit max, hidden input, only numbers and number pad is showing on both android and ios.

```html
<input
  type="number"
  id="password"
  name="password"
  pattern="[0-9]{4}"
  maxlength="4"
  style="-webkit-text-security: disc;"
  oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
/>
```

Note that `-webkit-text-security` is [not supported in Firefox or IE](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_-webkit-text-security).

Answer (score 3):

if you use the input field with password type, the digit should be shown as bullet points instead of the actual number.

```
<form action="">
Username: <input type="text" name="user"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
</form>
```

Comment: You could also add some js code to validate that they enter numeric, either on entry, or during the submit process.

Answer (score 0):

To add some functionaity to the pin:

```
pin = document.getelementByID("pin");

if(pin == 1234){
    window.open("page.html");
    //Any code after pin is correct
}
```