# How to make input type="tel" work as type="password"

Tags: javascript, html, css

When using the `input` tag as `type="tel"` the keyboard on touch devices correspond with the type of input box. However, I wish to keep the value in the `input` tag hidden (as with the `password` type).
The normal behaviour would be to have each character hidden as the user is typing.

```
<input type="tel">
```

```css
input [type="tel"] {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

This solution works in most browsers, but not in IE.

```
<input type="password" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

This solution doesn't work as expected.

Is there any way to accomplish what i'm trying to do?

Comment: While I don't have a definite answer for you, I will say that you *should* use `<input type="password" />` so that older browsers fall back gracefully to a simple password box that hides the characters - `type="tel"` is a validation thing and should be a secondary objective.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: `tel` is not just a validation thing as he wants the numeric keypad to popup on mobile devices.

Comment: dont forget that type = "password" is a "display-only" security feature  - simply swappingout hte entered content for predeetermined charackers (asterisks or dots) and NOT a real security feature

Comment: How about changing the input type dynamically with JS? Meaning have the input `type=number` so the numeric keyboard will pop upon focus, and after the first number is typed, change the type to `password` so the data will be hidden, I don't think the keyboard will change. It's just a thought and I did not test it

Comment: `inputmode` should be the way to go. If its a matter of browser support, trying `inputmode="tel"` would be another option. If that fails, the only thing left is to use `type="tel"` and emulate the "hide" behavior with Javascript.

Comment: This might be something to suggest for future versions; `type="pin"`

Comment: Thinking outside the box... Is there a font out there that is all dots?

Comment: @rybo111: You think of something like this: http://squigglefont.tripod.com/ :D

Comment: Something like an own numeric keypad could be a solution as well: http://a.kabachnik.info/jquery-numpad.html

Comment: @GiladArtzi Just tried your suggestion in Chrome for Android - the numerical pad changes to a standard keyboard when `type` is changed.

Comment: `This solution works in most browsers, but not in IE.` In most browsers???? It only works in chrome / safari!!! WTF?

Comment: @gavgrif just a reminder that `type = "password"` prevents copy/pasting the password to see what the asterisks are hiding, so I'd say **dont forget that type = "password" is ABSOLUTELY NOT a "display-only" security feature**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Update 2020-06-19

If all you're after is better usability for "pin" inputs, I'd now suggest sticking with the [inputmode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode) attribute that didn't work for OP in 2016. The browser support is still quite limited, but it's finally working at least on iOS Safari and as a solution it's much simpler and possibly more secure than avoiding `input type="password"` altoghether.

```html
<input type="password" inputmode="tel" />
```

So for OP's specific use-case I'd now recommend the above even though browser support is not 100%.
I know some people coming to this post are actually looking for `type="password"` alternatives for other reasons, like to circumvent password autocomplete, and my original answer below may still help them.

Also note that [my password font project that I recommend below](https://github.com/noppa/text-security) has had a few updates since I gave this answer and has a bit different installation instructions now.

---

#### Original answer

I know this already has a nice, working and accepted solution from *jdgregson*, but I really liked *rybo111*'s idea of a custom font based solution and wanted to give it a try.

The idea is to create a font that only contains circles so that when the font family is applied to the input element, seemingly no characters are displayed.

So in case anyone's still interested in a non-JS solution with [decent browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fontface) and without the known issues with jdgregson's answer, I created a simple font for this.

**GitHub repo**: https://github.com/noppa/text-security

**JSFiddle demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/449Lamue/6/

The font can be used by including the *dist/text-security.css* either from cloned repo or from RawGit or something similar. After including the css you can use the font by setting the element's `font-family` to `'text-security-disc'`.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/noppa/text-security/master/dist/text-security.css">
<style>
     input [type="tel"] {
         font-family: "text-security-disc";
         -webkit-text-security: disc;
     }
</style>
```

In the spirit of "polyfilling" the -webkit-text-security, I also added the "circle" and "square" options to use as the hiding symbol.

I've tested this with Chrome v49, IE11, Microsoft Edge 25 and Chrome v50 on Android 5.0, in which the input of type "tel" opens the number keypad.

Comment: This is the solution I would use, and will save this in case I need it. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I really like this. Especially the `-webkit-text-security` bit. That is the best solution if only it was portable. I updated my answer to address this.

Comment: Really appreciate  your involvement:)

Comment: No problem. I think this is something that could come in handy some day for my own projects too.

Comment: I tested this with IE mobile on Windows 8.1 and can confirm that it works perfectly +1

Comment: @noppa, I can't thank you enough!! Thanks a lot, working with all platforms, Android, web, Mozilla, and chrome. :)

Comment: @noppa, One issue I am having while using it with a screen reader. The screen reader is spelling the exact word which user has typed-in, instead of spell it like 'hidden' or 'dot'. Please let me know if something can be done to handle this scenario as well.

Answer (score 9):

There are several ways you can accomplish this:

### 1) -webkit-text-security

The most elegant solution is to use the builtin `-webkit-text-security: circle;` CSS style which is intended for this very thing. Unfortunately that is not portable, and isn't supported on IE or Edge. You can find a workaround to get support on other browsers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822548/degrading-webkit-text-security) if you choose to use this approach.

### 2) Changing the type to password after it is selected

As *Fidel90* and others have pointed out, you could try switching the `type="tel"` to `type="password"` after the user has selected it. I made a fiddle of that idea [here](https://jsfiddle.net/s54bex8v/3/). It works perfectly in iOS, but in Android it fails to launch the first tap, and then launches as the default keyboard on the second tap.

### 3) Using a font that has only one character

Another idea suggested by *rybo111* in the comments which has been implemented by *noppa* below is to use a font that has only a password dot character. This is likely the most portable and least hackish solution. One drawback is that the user cannot see the character they just typed as is the usual behaviour for modern mobile password fields. A comprehensive fiddle of this is posted [here](https://jsfiddle.net/449Lamue/6/).

### 4) Copy the text into a hidden input as the user types

My idea (below) is to use a second input to store the real number and then hide the number as the user types it. Note that this will filter all non-phone number characters from the final number, though you can modify the variable to accept whatever you want.

**Tested and works on:**

- iOS 9 Safari
- Android 6.0 Chrome
- Internet Explorer 11
- FireFox 45
- Chrome 50
- Opera 36
- Microsoft Edge 25

```js
var BACKSPACE_CHARS = [8, 46, 229];

function hideNumber(fakeInput, event) {
    var hideChar = '*';
    // add characters that you want to appear in the final number to this
    // string -- leave the string empty to allow all characters
    var phoneChars = '0123456789()-+';
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    var key = String.fromCharCode(keyCode)+'';
    var realInput = document.getElementById("hidden-number");
    var len = fakeInput.value.length;
    fakeInput.value = '';
    if(phoneChars.indexOf(key) > -1 || !phoneChars.length) {
        realInput.value += key;
    } else {
        if(BACKSPACE_CHARS.indexOf(keyCode) < 0) {
            --len;
        }
    }
    for(var i=0; i<len; i++) { // no String.repeat() in IE :(
        fakeInput.value += hideChar;
    }
    updateDisplay();
}

function backspace(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
    var realInput = document.getElementById("hidden-number");
    if(BACKSPACE_CHARS.indexOf(keyCode) > -1) { // backspace or delete
        var len = realInput.value.length;
        realInput.value = realInput.value.slice(0, len-1);
    } 
    updateDisplay();
}

function updateDisplay() {
    var realInput = document.getElementById("hidden-number");
    var display = document.getElementById("display");
    display.innerHTML = realInput.value || '';
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" name="number" id="number-hider" onkeypress="hideNumber(this, event)" onkeydown="backspace(event)" onblur="hideNumber(this)">
<input type="hidden" name="realnumber" id="hidden-number">
<div id="display"></div>
```

**Known bugs:**

- If a user taps or clicks in the middle of the text box and types or backspaces, the characters will be added or deleted from the end of the real number.

Comment: Your solution will not work if user type his number very fast, the event will be triggered only once.

Comment: For me it works as fast as I type, as long as I actually lift my finger off of the last key before pressing the next. I'll fix that with onkeydown.

Comment: @jdgregson : Not Working in IE browsers

Comment: @jdgregson: Great solution (didn't test on mobile so far). Working great in FF except one edge case: I enter some numbers and then set the cursor somewhere in the middle of the input and start deleting so that the values go out of sync.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like it should work decently. I actually haven't tested mobile either, SO's "Run code snippet" doesn't support mobile :/ I'll have to throw a test page online. But that's interesting. Maybe I could detect the cursor position with textbox.selectionStart and delete from there? But it is a pretty far edge case as most people would delete the whole password and reenter it if they can't see what they're deleting.

Comment: @jdgregson: It's a very edgy edge case, true. But on a production site I would not be surprised if someone tries this out of nothing (like I did) :-) Btw: You can create a jsFiddle that also works on mobile.

Comment: @Fidel90 You've gotta cover everything a user could think of. And I need to work on backspacing anyway. I tested it on mobile and: Safari iOS 9: perfect, numerical keyboard, hidden chars and all. Android Chrome: also perfect, except backspace doesn't work at all. You can almost never win with so many browsers :P

Comment: @Fidel90 aha! Backspace == 229 on mobile Chrome, I should have known.

Comment: @jdgregson: :-) Have my upvote for your effort and for providing the best solution so far.

Comment: Letters don't appear hidden at the moment.

Comment: @Fidel90 Thanks, that means a lot as someone who is finally contributing and not just reading.

Comment: @rybo111 That is by design as the question is about phone numbers. It could be modified to take more characters without much effort.

Comment: I implemented your #2 proposed solution, and it worked on the Android device used to test (probably Chrome browser).

Answer (score 8):

Using [noppa's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36950075/1399491) and his GitHub font and [jdgregson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36936452/1399491), here's a turnkey CSS solution ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gc23yku0/10/)):

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "password-mask";
  src: url(data:font/woff;charset:utf-8;base64,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) format("woff");
}
.numeric-password {
  font-family: password-mask;
}
.numeric-password::placeholder {
  font-family: initial;
}
```

```html
<input type="tel" class="numeric-password" placeholder="test" />
```

To support older iOS and Android devices, you would just need to add another data URI font-face definition with the ttf file for the password mask font.  Same for IE with the eot font file but most modern browsers support woff and should work with this CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/200kg1L2/2/) that replaces the initial `tel` with an `password` input as soon as you focus it (jQuery needed):

```js
var value = "",
 isPWD = false;

$('#wrap')
  .on("focus", "#input", function() {
   if (!isPWD) {
      var pass = $('<input id="input" type="password">');
      $(this).replaceWith(pass);
      isPWD = true;
      pass.focus();
    }    
  })
  .on("change", "#input", function() {
   value = $(this).val();
    $("#span").text(" = " + value);
  })
  .on("blur", "#input", function() {
   var tel = $('<input id="input" type="tel">');
    $(this).replaceWith(tel);
    isPWD = false;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrap">
  <input id="input" type="tel"/>
  <span id="span"></span>
</div>
```

I did not test this on a mobile device so far so I'm not sure if bringing the numeric pad up to the user works in every case.

**EDIT:** At least my mobile IE did not show a numeric pad but only the standard text field.

Comment: When I tap the input on Chrome for Android, it does nothing

Comment: Hmm...I guess this solution does not fit the specific needs of mobile devices very good :-/

Comment: I can't leave well enough alone. I tried your solution in pure JavaScript and it works perfectly for iOS, but not for Android. It's really so elegant, I wish it was portable. https://jsfiddle.net/s54bex8v/3/