# Is there any way to show bullets instead of numbers in input field

Tags: css, html, fonts

I require to show the bullets instead of numbers in my input field. for that is there any easiest way? I like to use some bullet based fonts so number will be hidden.

if so, any one share me a free fonts which gives only bullets for numbers?

```
<input type="tel" value="&#9679;">
```

I tried like above. but still i like to go for `bullet` fonts.

Comment: type="password"

Comment: `type="password"`?

Comment: No, I don't want to add type as password here, because some time later i need to show numbers in the same field, that's what i am looking for a font family. it is like temporarily masking requirement

Comment: well next time specify this in your question maybe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make input type="tel" work as type="password"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935576/how-to-make-input-type-tel-work-as-type-password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the ability to view and hide it's value, you could use a bit of JS to set its type attribute to tel or password?

```
<input type="password" id="field">
<script>const toggleVisibility = () => {
    let element = document.querySelector("#field");
    element.setAttribute("type", (element.getAttribute("type") == "password") ? "tel" : "password");
}
</script>
```

Hope that helps, if that's not what you're looking for, then you might find this CSS property useful: `-webkit-text-security: disc;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
input {
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```