# Is it possible to truly disable autofill and autocomplete for password fields for modern browsers?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, cross-browser

In modern browsers the standard of autofill and autocomplete is to completely ignore `autocomplete="off"` for password fields that are placed in a `form`. And insert saved passwords, even if it's in a user management page. Although the reason is in the right place, it makes creating a user management page a huge pain.

My team's web application runs with angular 7 and currently only supports chrome. But there's a big possibility that we will need support other browsers like internet explorer, edge, firefox, etc.

I know this is a largely touched subject, and that I can find many questions with answers similar to this question ([like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36935576/how-to-make-input-type-tel-work-as-type-password), [or this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769429/get-input-type-text-to-look-like-type-password)). But every solution I've found so far has at least one big flaw.

What I've tried so far on chrome:

### 1) Use `autocomplete="new-password"`

It seems that chrome/chromium developers ignores even this for `type="password"`.

### 2) Use `type="text" autocomplete="new-password"` with asterisk font family

This disables chrome from auto-filling the input field and hides the letters. But the big flaw is that the value is still there and can be copy-pasted in a different font family. The input field also loses the security of `type="password"` and any hacker can easily get the value.

### 3) Use -webkit-text-security

This is pretty much the same solution as the one before but this isn't even css standard and few browsers support it.

### 4) Replace value with *

This is the trickiest solution I've tried so far. When input value is changed I call a function in typescript that: Adds the new character to a local string, Change DOM value to * equal to the amount of characters, Return the locally saved value on `(blur)`.

This leaves me with a large amount of problems to deal with including: Erasing any character in the string removes the last character always, In addition to the last problem the first character will always stay the same even if the value is completely erased, Having to know where in the string to remove characters.

This solution is less than ideal.

### 5) Disable password management for domain in browser settings

This really isn't a solution to the problem as it means that I expect the users to turn off password management for domain. It would also result in not saving the password on the login page as many users may need.

### 6) Randomise `[name]` and `[autocomplete]` values

By one way binding said values to a randomised string based on current time, I can ensure that the password field doesn't match any fields saved by the browser. Although many has reported that this works between all browsers, this doesn't seem to work for me at all when using chrome. For me chrome shows recommended password as long as the input is of `type="password"`.

---

Solutions I've seen so far:

### 1) Use two input fields

This seems to me to work the same as my own solution 4). And will probably be just as troublesome to work with.

### 2) Use jQuery Disable Auto Fill Plugin

This seem to be very close to what I'm looking for but the problem is that it uses jQuery. All I can say is that I've been told that we're not using jQuery and that I probably won't be able to use the plugin directly.

I'm currently looking for a way to implement this using angular and would love any help or directions on this.

---

If you know of any solution that I haven't mentioned above, please post an answer or drop me a link in comments.

Comment: The best I have been able to get is to use a random function to set autocomplete and name: the result is something  like: *autocomplete="mbshftbaqo" name="mbshftbaqo"* Of course this will change when the page re-renders

Comment: @vals I've managed to randomise values on both autocomplete and name by using local value that are randomised based on current time: "this.rndName = String.fromCharCode(65 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26)) + Date.now();" but nothing happens. if I ignore randomising name and autocomplete and only use autocomplete="new-password" on password field. It disables autofill for username and password fields, but still give me username/password suggestions on the password field in my form.

Any idea why?

Comment: i think as long as `autocomplete="new-password"` is not supported by all common browsers, there won't be a true solution. 
For me personally i found out that two input fields work the best. I just got one hidden field that captures the auto fill in my layout - i agree that it is hacky but i haven't encountered any problems yet.

Comment: @EliasJohannes I tried using hidden fields but when fields are hidden, chrome finds the best first for me. Could you link me a working example of this?

Comment: @kebbaben it doesn't really demonstrate well in a fiddle but here's the code i used: https://jsfiddle.net/EliasJohannes/wtz6v145/2/ 
i tested it on FF, Chrome & IE and it works for me (i realized i also set `autocomplete` on the whole form)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution I've found so far is to use `type="text"` on password field and use `autocomplete="off"` on the form and every input field in it.

I won't mark this as an answer however as it still has the great flaw of losing the `type="password"` security functionality. Text fields also allows spell check which can be disabled with `spellcheck="false"`. But I've read that it's possible to override this with browser settings.

This question will remain unanswered until a better solution is proposed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I came accross this problem yesterday and made this solution:

```js
function getCaretPosition() {
  if (window.getSelection && window.getSelection().getRangeAt) {
    let range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
    let selectedObj = window.getSelection();
    let rangeCount = 0;
    let childNodes = selectedObj.anchorNode.parentNode.childNodes;
    for (let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
      if (childNodes[i] == selectedObj.anchorNode) {
        break;
      }
      if (childNodes[i].outerHTML)
        rangeCount += childNodes[i].outerHTML.length;
      else if (childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
        rangeCount += childNodes[i].innerText ? childNodes[i].innerText.length : 0;
      }
    }
    return range.startOffset + rangeCount;
  }
  return -1;
}

let secret_word_placeholder_elem = document.getElementById('secret_word_placeholder');
let secret_word_elem = document.getElementById('password');

secret_word_placeholder_elem.onkeypress = function(e) {

  let caretPosition = getCaretPosition();
  let entered_character = String.fromCharCode(e.key.charCodeAt(0));
  secret_word_elem.value = [secret_word_elem.value.slice(0, caretPosition), entered_character, secret_word_elem.value.slice(caretPosition)].join('');

  console.log("password: " + secret_word_elem.value);
}
```

```css
#secret_word_placeholder {
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
  /* all styles below this line are optional */
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-user-select: text;
  cursor: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="form-group">

  <div class="row">

    <label class="col-md-3 text-right">Password:</label>

    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div contentEditable="true" style="height: auto;" class="form-control" id="secret_word_placeholder"></div>
      <input style="visibility: hidden; display: none" type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```