# How to have an input field be numbers and password type at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an input field to enter pin. In mobile devices I want the pin to not be displayed in plain text like the password input field. I found this suggestion in stackoverflow for this but none of it has worked so far

```
<input type="password" name="PIN" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" style="-webkit-text-security: disc;" required>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Input field for PIN code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418453/input-field-for-pin-code)

Comment: Can you explain more? it seems you need an input not showing the characters. am I right? your code should be work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS for that

```css
#password{
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
    -moz-text-security:circle;
     text-security:circle;
}
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="password" pattern="[0-9]*" >
```

You can do that with tons of ways the easiest is with CSS
Hope that helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `type="password"` to `type="number"`.  I believe the password input type prevents the numeric keyboard on mobile devices.  This will still only work on webkit browsers but webkit is used in a large percentage of mobile browsers at this point.

```html
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" style="-webkit-text-security:disc;">
```

Besides this, there is no surefire way to ensure both a password and numeric input on mobile devices without using javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use javascript

```js
let mobileInput  = document.getElementById('mobile');

mobileInput.oninput = function(){
  // if empty
 if(!this.value) return;

 // if non numeric
 let isNum = this.value[this.value.length - 1].match(/[0-9]/g);
 if(!isNum) this.value = this.value.substring(0, this.value.length - 1);
}
```

```html
<input id="mobile" type="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

This option will bring up the numeric keyboard and filter numbers only.

```
<input inputmode="numeric" type="password" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');" />
```