# -webkit-text-security: disc; css property is not working in Firefox browser

Tags: css

-webkit-text-security: disc;  css property is not working in Firefox browser

Is there any alternative for same in mozilla . Please help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Updated Code:

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: text-security-disc;
  src: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noppa/text-security/master/dist/text-security-disc.woff");
}

input {
  font-family: text-security-disc;
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

---

---

Note:- If you dont want `password` as input type,
the only way I could think of is to use 'disc' like font, for the input. I don't recommend this, since anyone can copy-paste the password to text editor and see it. If you want to proceed, here is [link](https://github.com/noppa/text-security) to a github repository. (I haven't tested it, so I am not sure)

Comment: type=“Password” shows password recommendations and autocomplete off not working for forms and textfields

Comment: @AmanSingh Its working. See newly updated Answer above. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man , it is working in all the browsers. It was really helpful

Comment: Hi @TechySharnav , it is working fine in all the browsers, instead giving the url of the site I want to download it in local and and run it in the localhost , how to do that ?

Comment: @AmanSingh Copy and paste the url into browser's address bar. It will then download the file, that you can save it locally. Then simply change the URL in code, relative to the locally downloaded file

Comment: This has a bug when pasting emoji into the field which don't get masked.

Comment: @silverwind It does work in Chrome on Android. Not tested on Desktop. Emojis are also unicode characters, so they should also get masked.

Comment: I meant in Firefox specifically. There seems to be no workaround, so this hack is not completely cross-browser unfortunately. Webkit-based browsers have a different bug where they see a emoji as two characters so render two discs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show placeholder:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#NewPassword").keydown(function () {            
            $(this).css('font-family', 'initial');  
            $(this).css('-webkit-text-security', 'unset');            
    });

    $("#NewPassword").on("keyup blur", function () {        
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {                
            $(this).css('font-family', 'text-security-disc');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: text-security-disc;
  src: url("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/noppa/text-security/master/dist/text-security-disc.woff");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="NewPassword" maxlength="50" name="NewPassword" placeholder="password" type="text">
```